# Why does this javascript code not exit cleanly?

Tags: javascript

When I run this code using node on the command line, it just hangs instead of returning after printing zero. I understand the thing about why "this" is not incrementing "age" because of the function scope changing the reference to "this".

```js
function Person() {
  // The Person() constructor defines `this` as an instance of itself.
  this.age = 0;

  setInterval(function growUp() {
    // In non-strict mode, the growUp() function defines `this` 
    // as the global object, which is different from the `this`
    // defined by the Person() constructor.
    this.age++;
  }, 1000);
}

var p = new Person();

console.log(p.age);
```

Comment: The event loop always has a message queued. The process won't exit if there is more left for it to do. Did you mean setTimeout instead of setInterval?

Comment: Define "exit cleanly"? You get the issue with `this`, and of course `setInterval` is async so even with the correct `this` it would change the value one second after you've printed it. Node command line doesn't exit as long as there is async code waiting to execute, and your interval never ends. You have to either stop the interval at some point, or call `process.exit()` to exit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hanging because `setInterval` runs asynchronously, and also runs forever. Node (and other command line programs) often buffer output and don't print it immediately, sometimes even waiting until the app is ready to terminate. That's probably what is happening in this case.

Try changing `setInterval` to `setTimeout` and see if you get your console log to print then.

**Update**

As mentioned by cdbajorin, `setInterval` and `setTimeout` both return a `Timeout` object (on Node at least, in browser they return numeric IDs) which you can pass into `clearTimeout` and `clearInterval` to cancel them.

https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_args

Comment: Yeah that works, thanks. I was skimming over that function because I thought it was just a user defined function and not a built-in.

Comment: worth mentioning that `setInterval()` returns an instance of `Timeout`, which is cancelable with `.close()`.

Comment: Good point, I'll update. I don't remember it returning a Timeout instance though, docs say it just returns a number, but that's still useful info to have.

Comment: I should probably clarify that it is dependent on the environment. `.close()` is used in node.

Comment: Ah, that's an excellent point. And node is what is being used here, so that is pertinent information.

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear out the interval that you have steed up by using setInterval. It keeps on executing after the time you have given. Which gives you a result of lagging but that just a set interval. 
Use:

```
var x = setInterval(function() {
    // In non-strict mode, the function defines `this` 
    // as the global object, which is different from the `this`
    // defined by the Person() constructor.
    this.age++;
}, 1000);
window.clearInterval(x); // for clearing the interval
```